# NotifyOfPropertyChange of the child view

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a view control which displays child view control inside ConctentControl element.
Parent ViewModel has a property which holds child ViewModel.
Parent view is a list and child view displays the properties of the selected object from the list.
Parent View:

```
<ContentControl Name="LayerPropertiesView"/>
```

Parent ViewModel:

```
public LayerPropertiesPanelViewModel LayerPropertiesView { get; } = new LayerPropertiesPanelViewModel();
```

Each element in the list has a properties button. Clicking on this button should display properties in the child view. Parent ViewModel click action handler gets the object to display as a parameter. It sets the new object to child's ViewModel Property and notifies child's View

```
public void ShowTopLayerProperties(object dataContext)
{
    LayerPropertiesView.SelectedLayer = (JobDummy)dataContext;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LayerPropertiesView.SelectedLayer);
}
```

Child view is not updated :(

Comment: Does your child vew models implement the PropertyChangedBase class?  You would have to and  then trigger  the change notification from inside the child model's property.

Comment: Yes it does. How will child model know that parent's view changed?

Comment: Could you show the code from `SelectedLayer`.

Comment: Setting properties on the child view model will trigger the notification event. If your parent view doesen't bind directly to the child view model you will have to delegate those changes explicitly e.g. by using events. E.g. if UserName property on the parent view model changes you would have to select the proper data context and assign it to the child view model property for the child view to bind to. I thinmk you have to check your 'ShowTopLayerProperties()' call. Does it execute?

Comment: You can use Event Aggregators to notify the child.